# How to prove a sequence of random variables follow normal distribution in the setting of classical linear regression

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, regression

[image]

Hi, I have a bit trouble proving a part of question 4) and question 5).

For question 4), I can prove that those random variables are independent by showing that the doc product between any two of them is zero. However, for the second part, which is to prove that those random variables follow the normal distribution, I am not sure how to approach it. I know the random error e_i epsilon follows the normal distribution and q_i is a unit vector, but how to prove that their product also follows normal distribution? Any hints will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

For question 5), I guess I just don't know how to prove a random variable follows a certain distribution in general. So I might gain some insights from the help for question 4) and reattempt to solve question 5). Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think you should come across the following result on linear combination of the components of a multivariate normal random vector:- Let $\mathbf{X} \sim \mathbb{N}_p(\mu, \Sigma)$. For any $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{R}^p$, $\mathbf{a'X} \sim \mathbb{N}_p\left( \mathbf{a'} \mu, \mathbf{a'} \Sigma \mathbf{a} \right)$. This can be easily proved by uniqueness of characteristic function of multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Oh, I will try this. Thanks a lot!